# php do while not equal not ending

Tags: php

trying to use a do while loop but it never finishes. Can't figure out why

```
<?php

$a = "2018-11-28T14:36:27+00:00";
$b = "2018-11-28T14:43:27+00:00.";

if ($a !== $b) {
    echo "not equal";
}
else {
        echo "equal";
}

do {
    echo "a";
} while ($a !== $b);
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to finish? Nothing changes once it starts, so the exit condition can never be met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do while statement :

"The expression in a do-while statement is evaluated after the body of the loop is executed. Therefore, the body of the loop is always executed at least once."

[additionnal explaination from php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

"do-while loops are very similar to while loops, except the truth expression is checked at the end of each iteration instead of in the beginning. The main difference from regular while loops is that the first iteration of a do-while loop is guaranteed to run (the truth expression is only checked at the end of the iteration), whereas it may not necessarily run with a regular while loop (the truth expression is checked at the beginning of each iteration, if it evaluates to FALSE right from the beginning, the loop execution would end immediately). "

because do while body is exectued at least one time it will echo "a" but your condition is always true and you don't change your values into do while body; then you will get an infinite loop